# Returning data from a PouchDB query

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I'm having a problem returning data from a PouchDB query. I'm trying to build a function that, when called, returns specific data from a PouchDB. Here is my code:

```
function getUserFullName() {
            var db = "userInfo";
            var pouch = new PouchDB(db);
            pouch.get("token").then(function (result) {
            console.log(result-user_real_name);
                return result.user_real_name;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

So what happens is that the function returns an undefined. Does anyone have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you console log just the result and see if you actually getting one? console.log("pouchdb result", result); before the return.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure its getting data back.

Comment: Post the result object please.

Comment: @axtscz how are you running this function? pouch.get is an async function. If you run getUserFullName synchronously you wont get a result. getUserFullName needs a callback as a parameter

Comment: s/result-user_real_name/result.user_real_name/

Comment: try debugging with `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it looks likes you are running "getUserFullName" synchronously, but you have an asynchronous function inside of it, "pouch.get". The return value of that asynchronous function needs to be returned in a callback or a promise.

If "pouch.get" returns a promise, as you are showing above with the ".then" you can write your code like this:

```
function getUserFullName() {
  var db = "userInfo";
  var pouch = new PouchDB(db);

  return pouch.get("token")
}
```

And run it like this:

```
getUserFullName()
  .then(function(fullUserName){
    console.log(fullUserName);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Let me know if that works, or if you have any questions. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Looks like "pouch.get" does return a promise. See an example in their [docs here](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document). Therefore, this code will work.

Comment: It works, the problem I'm having is that it is still running asynchronously. Code that is dependent on its result is being run before it returns a value.

Comment: @axtscz Code that is dependent on this result should go inside the ".then" function of "getUserFullName." Where it says "console.log(fullUserName)." That will be the result of "getUserFullName". "getUserFullName" has to run asynchronously because it is dependent on the results from a database query.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thanks!