# Handle result from pouchdb document

Tags: javascript, ionic4, pouchdb

I would like to use result of a query in Pouchdb.

Here is a sample :

```
this.obsLocal = new PouchDB('observateurlocal');

        this.obsLocal.allDocs({
            include_docs: true,
            attachments: true
            }).then(function (result) {

               return result.rows[0].doc.id_observateur;

            }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });    

        console.log(this.obsLocal);
```

I wish to print out the observateur id from the document
Do i have to write a function as explained here [Returning data from a PouchDB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400079/returning-data-from-a-pouchdb-query)
?

Answer (score 0):

Because the calls to get data from the database are asynchronous, printing an id must either be done in the "then" part of your code ie just before the return statement, or (better) you can call a function at that point to print the ids. So something like this...

```
this.obsLocal = new PouchDB('observateurlocal');

        this.obsLocal.allDocs({
            include_docs: true,
            attachments: true
            }).then(function (result) {
               printDbIDs(result.rows);
               return result.rows[0].doc.id_observateur;

            }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });    

        console.log(this.obsLocal);

   function printDbIDs(my_rows) {
     console.log(my_rows[0].doc.id_observateur);
   }
```

Comment: I think i should use async and await with promise in ionic but i don't know how to

Comment: If you need to use async/await then you should research that pattern and if you are stumped then pose a *new* question regarding async/await.  IanC answered your question.

Comment: Also, this [We have a problem with promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)

Comment: Frank - async/await is really Promises with a different syntax. With either, you need to wait for the database system to respond and then use the result. RamblinRose pointed out a great article on promises by Nolan Lawson - it really helped me when I first started learning about this.